# Ionic2 first project error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to follow these instruction : http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/installation/

But I have error with this line :
`ionic start cutePuppyPics --v2`

```
Creating Ionic app in folder C:\dev\debug npm\cutePuppyPics based on tabs projec
t
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.zip
Error with start Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:552:26)
Error Initializing app: Error: read ECONNRESET
 Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:552:26)
Caught exception:
 Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:552:26)

Mind letting us know? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues
```

Does anyone can help me ?

Thanks by advance !

Comment: can you download it with direct link to  https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.zip in your browser?

Comment: What should I do after dowload it ?

Comment: nothing to do, this is just test for network problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just like @[AnatolyS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2126582/anatolys) says, that seems to be a network problem. Once you download it, (and unzip it) open a console at the same level you see a file called `package.json` and run `npm install`. That will install all the required dependencies for the project.

Once that is done, run `ionic serve` and the application should be opened in the browser.

Comment: After adding a ionic.config.json and following your instructions it works, thanks !

Comment: Just in case, the `ionic.config.json` file can be automatically added by running `ionic start`.

Comment: Finally, it works with ionic serve but not with this : `ionic start MyIonic2Project tutorial --v2` I have the same error as previously.